# I'm not able to call a named callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make a function and call it from another function as a callback. My code below has been butchered up for troubleshooting, but I was attempting to name as many of my functions as possible to make it cleaner. I have had some success by un-naming the functions and making them all anonymous inline.

I'm specifically confused by the declaration of variables inside the parenthesis of the function definition.

```
function pickRnd (err, res, pullQuestions) {
      var i = 0;
      var qSelects = new Array(); 
      qSelects.k1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.n);
      qSelects.k2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.n);
      while ( qSelects.k2 == qSelects.k1 ) {
        qSelects.k2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.n);
        i++;
        if (i == 20) {break;}
      }
      qSelects.k3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.n);
      while ( qSelects.k3 == qSelects.k2 || qSelects.k3 == qSelects.k1 ) {
        qSelects.k3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * res.n);
        i++;
        if (i == 40) {break;}
      }
      console.log('::' + qSelects.k1);
      console.log('::' + qSelects.k2);
      console.log('::' + qSelects.k3);

      function pullQuestions(qSelects) {
        console.log('function pullQuestions start');
        var qArray = new Object();
        db.records.findOne({}).skip(qSelects.k1, function(err, result) {
          qArray.push(result);
        });
        db.records.findOne({}).skip(qSelects.k2, function(err, result) {
          qArray.push(result);
        });
        db.records.findOne({}).skip(qSelects.k3, function(err, result) {
          qArray.push(result);
        });
        console.log('2' + qArray);
      };
    }

module.exports = function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  db.records.runCommand('count', function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.n);
    pickRnd(null, res);
  });
}
```

Comment: The identifiers in a formal parameter list (such as *err*, *res* and *pullQuestions*) are effectively the same as declaring them at the very top of the function. However, declaring a same–named function within the function overwrites a value passed in the call (since declared functions are created effectively as local variables and assigned a value of the function body before any code is executed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared a third argument to `pickRnd` and called it `pullQuestions`. But in your `pickRnd` body, you've also declared a function with the name `pullQuestions`.

When you call `pickRnd`, you aren't passing it three arguments, which suggests you don't want to list that third argument in the `pickRnd` arguments list.

But you don't actually *call* `pullQuestions` anywhere in your `pickRnd` function, so it doesn't make sense to declare it there.

---

> I'm specifically confused by the declaration of variables inside the parenthesis of the function definition.

Those aren't variables, though they're similar to variables. They're *arguments*. They're things the function expects to receive from its caller when it's called. Simpler example:

```
function foo(a) {
    console.log("a = " + a);
}
```

`foo` expects to receive an argument when you call it. `foo` will refer to that argument using the name `a`. So during this call:

```
foo(42);
```

...in the `foo` code, `a` will be `42`.

In contrast, *variables* are normally internal to the function. For instance:

```
function foo(a) {
    var b;
    b = a * 2;
    console.log("a = " + a);
    console.log("b = " + b);
}
```

Now, `foo` expects to receive a single argument, which it calls `a`, and separately `foo` declares a local variable `b` that it will use internally.

---

Regarding calling named functions and/or callbacks, perhaps another simple example will help: Let's assume we have `foo` and `foo` will call a callback function we pass into it:

```
function foo(count, callback) {
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
        callback(n);
    }
}
```

If we call `foo`, it will call the callback we give it `count` times with a number starting at `0` and increasing by one each time. So here's an anonymous function as a callback:

```
foo(5, function(x) {
    console.log(x);
});
```

```js
function foo(count, callback) {
  var n;
  for (n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
    callback(n);
  }
}

foo(5, function(x) {
  snippet.log(x);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Here's an example of a named function, `bar`, as the callback:

```
function bar(x) {
    console.log(x);
}

foo(5, bar);
```

```js
function foo(count, callback) {
  var n;
  for (n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
    callback(n);
  }
}

function bar(x) {
  snippet.log(x);
}

foo(5, bar);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks this is extremely helpful. Also I notice that a space between the function name and the parenthesis is important during declaration. That was causing me some grief too.

Comment: @xdaxdb: Glad that helps. No, there's no need for a space between the function name and the opening parenthesis in a function declaration (see above, I'm not using one in any of the declarations above). You *do* need a space after `function` before the function name, of course, or you get `functionfoo` which is, of course, just one token. (In fact, in the code above, the spaces in `function foo`, `function bar`, and `var n` are the only significant spaces in the entire code outside a string literal.)

Comment: wow, its weird because I can change the output of my code by adding/removing a space between `function` and `()` I have been up all night though so I could be wrong.